# Save & access "named version" of Google Sheet via GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

In Google Sheets there is an option to saved a "named version" of a sheet. I am looking for a way to do this programatically. Roughly, I want a button press to:

- Create a new named version (eg, "v3") of a spreadsheet (`data`)
- Create a copy of another spreadsheet (`calculator`)
- Have `calculator` reference data in "v3" of `data`.

Is this possible? I can't find any functions to programatically create/access versions of spreadsheets. In the [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/), or [Drive Web API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-sdk).

Comment: Oh you meant literally different versions within gdrive, I'm sorry my info below won't help you :(

Answer (score -3):

Yes, this is possible.

Steps:

- Create  calculator
- Have calculator use data from a sheet that is an imported range from
  v1 (or whatever)

Scripting steps:

- Copy calculator (DriveApp)
- Copy v1 into v3 (DriveApp)
- Open calculator (SpreadsheetApp)
- Change import range function in calculator data
  sheet (SpreadsheetApp)